# JS coordinates from commands

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, coordinates, calculation

I have some task to resolve, when we need to renew the coordinates array from commands, like this.
when forward - y is adding 1, back - y minus 1, right - x plus 1 and left - x minus 1. But something is not working properly here.

```
function getLocation(coordinates, commands) {
  // write code here
  let x = coordinates[0]
  let y = coordinates[1]
  //let newCoordinates = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
     if (i === 'forward' ) {
          y += 1 ;
          }
       if (i === 'back') {
         y -= 1 ;
      }
      if (i === 'right') {
      x +=  1;
      }
      if (i === 'left') {
      x -= 1;
    }

 }
 //newCoordinates.push(x, y)
return coordinates;

}
 console.log(getLocation([0, 0], ['forward', 'forward', 'left']))
```

Comment: You're checking if `i` is any of the commands, but `i` is the index in the array; `0`, `1`, `2`, etc. I think you meant to do `commands[i] === 'forward'`?

Answer (score 2):

You're not accessing the values in the `commands` array when looping. At the moment you're comparing if the `i` is either `'forward'`, `'back'`, or any other command.

What you should be doing is comparing each value in the `commands` array by accessing the value. `commands[i] === 'forward'`, and so forth.

Returning the `coordinates` array will not give you the updated values, as modifying `x` and `y` don't update the values in the `coordinates` array. The easiest way to solve this by returning a new array with `x` and `y` in it, like so: `return [x, y];`

```js
function getLocation(coordinates, commands) {
  let x = coordinates[0]
  let y = coordinates[1]

  for (let i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
    if (commands[i] === 'forward') {
      y += 1;
    }
    
    if (commands[i] === 'back') {
      y -= 1;
    }
    
    if (commands[i] === 'right') {
      x += 1;
    }
    
    if (commands[i] === 'left') {
      x -= 1;
    }
  }
  
  return [x, y];
}

console.log(getLocation([0, 0], ['forward', 'forward', 'left']))
```

I also took the liberty to modify your function to use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) as an example on how you could implement the function in a different way. Don't know if it will help you out, but I assume you're still learning and this might expand your knowledge base.

```js
function getLocation([x, y], ...commands) {
  for (command of commands) {
    if (command === 'forward') {
      y += 1;
    }
    
    else if (command === 'back') {
      y -= 1;
    }
    
    else if (command === 'right') {
      x += 1;
    } 
    
    else if (command=== 'left') {
      x -= 1;
    }
  }
  
  return [x, y];
}

console.log(getLocation([0, 0], 'forward', 'forward', 'left'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using index for checking the command, you should use values of array in conditional statement like this

```js
function getLocation(coordinates, commands) {
  let x = coordinates[0]
  let y = coordinates[1]
  let newCoordinates = [];
  
  commands.forEach((command) => {
      if (command === 'forward' ) {
          y += 1 ;
      }
      if (command === 'back') {
         y -= 1 ;
      }
      if (command === 'right') {
        x +=  1;
      }
      if (command === 'left') {
        x -= 1;
      }
  })

  newCoordinates.push(x, y)
  return newCoordinates;

}
 console.log(getLocation([0, 0], ['forward', 'forward', 'left']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
function getLocation(coord, commands) {
  $.each(commands, function(i, command) {
    switch (command) {
      case 'forward':
        coord[1]++;
        break;
      case 'back':
        coord[1]--;
        break;
      case 'right':
        coord[0]++;
        break;
      case 'left':
        coord[0]--;
    }
  });
  return coord;
}
console.log(getLocation([0, 0], ['forward', 'forward', 'left']))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is a very good `switch()` use. You do not need to separate the parts of the coordinates array; you can manipulate the values in the array with operators `++` and `--`.

You can use `$.each()` from jQuery or a `for()` loop. No advantage to either in this case.

Answer (score 0):

One could implement `command`-functions, each mapping a possible command's name/key, with each function expecting and returning an `{ x, y }`-coordinate object.

The functions would be provided via an object-based lookup-table.

The `getLocation` function then can be implemented by executing the related `command`-function [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) of the provided `commandList`'s command-name, reassigning the `coords`-object's current state at every iteration, and finally returning the current `coords`-object's `x`/`y` values.

```js
const commandLookup = {
  forward: ({ x, y }) => ({ x, y: y + 1 }),
  back: ({ x, y }) => ({ x, y: y - 1 }),
  left: ({ x, y }) => ({ x: x - 1, y }),
  right: ({ x, y }) => ({ x: x + 1, y }),
};

function getLocation([x, y], commandList) {
  let coords = { x, y };

  commandList
    .forEach(commandKey =>
      // includes a fallback for non existing command-names.
      coords = commandLookup[commandKey]?.(coords) ?? coords
    );

  return [coords.x, coords.y];
}
console.log(
  "[0, 0] => ['forward', 'forward', 'left'] ...",
  getLocation([0, 0], ['forward', 'forward', 'left'])
);
console.log(
  "[1, 1] => ['left', 'left', 'FOO', 'back', 'back'] ...",
  getLocation([1, 1], ['left', 'left', 'FOO', 'back', 'back'])
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @NadiaDen ... The OP might check on the approach of the late provided, above answer.